# Can you double move a stinking cloud?

Tags: dnd-4e, wizard

In **D&D 4e**, a creature can perform a move action instead of a standard action, allowing them to perform two move actions in a turn.

**Stinking Cloud** allows you to create a zone and furthermore says:

> ...As a move action, you can move the zone up to 6 squares.

Can you move the stinking cloud twice in the same round?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**

If it says **Move Action** and they spend a move action, I'd let the character do it.

Just as an aside, as a D.M. I'd be thinking stationary target and **Opportunity Attacks**.

Answer (score 13):

The actual rule is (page 269, PHB):

> You can take a move action or a minor action instead of a standard action, and you can take a minor action instead of a move action.

There's no requirement for the two move actions to be the same (or different, for that matter).

So you can take any two move actions in a round, which can include moving a stinking cloud twice (or moving yourself and then moving the cloud, or retrieving something from a bag and then moving, etc.).